# How can get a WC product from another store via API and import it in my store?

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm on site A and I want to:

1. Retrieve a product from Site B by its id via API call.
2. Import it on site A with the exact same information (except for the ID, of course), or update it if a product with tha same SKU already exists.

The first step is pretty simple, but I'm having a hard time using the API response body to create a new product locally (or update it, if the SKU already exists).
I think there should be an easy way to do it.

I've tried the [WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Admin-Duplicate-Product.html) Class, but the `product_duplicate()` method requires a WC_Product type parameter, and all I have is the product data returned by the API.

Comment: https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/